# MapBox application don't shows the map. (Mapbox - Unity)

Tags: unity-game-engine, mapbox, mapbox-android

I am creating a geolocation application with MapBox in Unity, I am using one of the examples that come with MapBox, and I am also using one of the styles of maps that come with the example.

When you try it in unity, the map appears normally, but when you take it to an android device, the map does not appear, only the "character".

I do not know what the problem is that the only thing that changed was the character through the blue cube.
Thank you so much.

Application in Unity

[image: Aplication in Unity]

Application in Android

[image: Aplication in Android]

Answer (score 0):

To troubleshoot it might be helpful if we can take a look at your build and player settings as well as your abstract map configuration.

Answer (score 0):

You need to tick "Initialize on start" on the Abstract Map script.